# Optimizing for off-turn free action activity

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, optimization, free-action

I'm trying to develop a build for levels 3-6 that optimizes for the largest number of discrete free actions that need to be taken off-turn to work but don't explicitly grant themselves the ability to be used off-turn.  Stuff like 'drawing ammunition' and 'making an attack of opportunity' (the Melee Tactics Toolbox version, not the CRB version).  I want each ability's use not to need to presuppose the use of other similar abilities, though optional synergy between abilities (like using the feat Snap Shot to make off turn drawing, reloading, and firing required for the feat to work as intended) is a plus.

The character does *not* need to be good at anything, and the DM has waived BAB requirements for all feats and prestige classes.

Abilities that outright kill the character aren't helpful, though-- while I can rely on other party members to carry the fight and ensure I don't die from enemy actions, I do need to survive to proc more out-of-turn-free-action attempts, so things like [Troth of the Forgotten Pharaoh](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/troth-of-the-forgotten-pharaoh/) are a no go.

A complete build is not necessary, just the parts that are relevant to maximizing the free action attempts and an explanation of what's left to do.

The most important thing is the *number* of discrete free action abilities the character will attempt to use, and secondarily the number of such actions that can be attempted in a single round.

Free action abilities available to everyone but meeting the criteria for this question should be included in the build, preferably with a token piece of mundane equipment or such tied to its use (e.g. a bow and arrows for projectile weapon drawing, or a bastard sword for removing a hand from a versatile weapon, etc)

The motivation for the character is to explore the discrepancies between the assumptions present in the rulebooks, the assumptions present in the GM, and the assumptions present in the character, particularly through the aspects of the RPG resulting from the synthetic resolution of these discrepancies.

Comment: In the campaign is drawing a weapon as a free action *via* the feat [Quick Draw](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/quick-draw-combat-final/) something that can be done off-turn?

Comment: That's a decent example of the kind of thing I'm looking for (the answer to your question is unclear), though Quick Draw is still useful on-turn.  Drawing a thrown weapon off turn as part of an attack is definitely intended to be allowed, but no mention of the off-turnness is made.

Comment: Is the build supposed to be a sort-of nasty, hah-hah-I-told-you-so poke in the DM's eye or is this really for fun? (I'm just curious.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan for fun.  The idea is to talk about the rules as they come up so we can talk about the way we make rulings/interpret rules and what makes for good v.s. bad methodology on that count.  The DM is aware of the goal of this character and assures me that the methodology they have explained will work fine.  I do not think it will work.  The choice of rule (i.e. free actions) was essentially arbitrary; it'll work because the DM in question doesn't have a solid grasp of the free action rules and is using rationale that conflicts with his larger rationale but there are many such areas.

Comment: Also I like special free actions at early levels cause the whole game becomes off turn free actions at high levels and it's cool to bring some of that gameplay down to an arena where turns still end.

Comment: Maybe adding one example of an action like those you are thinking about would help to be clearer? Basically what I understand from your question is that you are looking for free action that you can't perform off-turn but that are not useful if you can't perform them off-turn.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Attacks of Opportunity are a good example.  They generally are talked about as if they happen out of turn, but don't specifically allow themselves to do so.

Comment: Are any of the free, swift, immediate action rules being modified or should we treat them as normal? Any race restrictions? Caster or martial preference?

Comment: @Visfarix no race restrictions but custom races must have RP in the standard bracket (0-10). Non-custom races don't have that restriction.  No caster/martial/race/class/whatever  restrictions going on.  The only change to the action rules that I'm aware of is that free actions aren't allowed out of turn unless they explicitly say so.